# Binding to DataTable with Select

Tags: c#, binding

I have a DataGrid control binded to DataTable using the following:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable1.DefaultView;
```

Now I would want to items in my DataGrid changes corresponding to user selection in a ComboBox. I.e. I will need to bind to the dataTable selectively? The following code works but I felt it's being overkill:

```
dataView1 = new DataView(
    dataTable1,
    "Combox_ID = " + comboBoxId,
    "ID ASC",
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);c
DataTable dataView1DataTable = dataView1.ToTable();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataDvDt.DefaultView;
```

Is there a simplier way to do this, something like the following but works?

```
/* below code doesn't work */
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable1.Select("ComboBox1_ID = 0").DefaultView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind to the `DataView` itself, like you're technically already doing.

```
var dv = new DataView(dataTable1, 
    "Combox_ID = " + comboBoxId, 
    "ID ASC",
    DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dv;
```

Unless you want to protect the original data from modification there's no need to create a new table copy.